# How can I use "weak" correctly?? or C function overriding

Tags: c, gcc

I want to use `__attribute__((weak))` correctly, for function overriding.

My code does not work as I expected.  What's wrong with it?

---

**common.h**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int __attribute__((weak)) doJob1(void);
int __attribute__((weak)) doJob2(int, int);

typedef int (*Job1)(void);
typedef int (*Job2)(int, int);
```

**common.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "common.h"

__attribute__((weak)) int doJob1(void)
{
        printf("doJob1 common WEAK\n");
        return 0;
}

__attribute__((weak)) int doJob2(int a, int b)
{
        printf("doJob2 common WEAK\n");
        return 0;
}
```

**driverA.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "common.h"

int doJob1(void)
{
        printf("doJob1 driverA Strong\n");
}

void main()
{
        Job1 j1 = doJob1;
        Job2 j2 = doJob2;

        j1();
        j2(0, 0);
}
```

When I run the program, I see:

```
sh> ./a.out
doJob1 common WEAK
doJob2 common WEAK
```

I expected this result, instead:

```
sh> ./a.out
doJob1 driverA Strong
doJob2 common WEAK
```

How can I obtain the expected result?

Overall, there are many functions of the form "Job1", "Job2"..."JobXX".
driverA wants to use its own functions for few jobs and common functions for for some jobs, and some functions will be NULL:

```
ex> 
Job1 - driverA_Job1
Job2 - common Job2
Job3 - NULL
..
```

A different driver, say driverB, may make different choices:

```
Job1 - common job1
job2 - B's own job2
job5 - NULL
```

How can I override functions correctly?

Comment: How do you compile your code ?

Comment: Why do you need function overriding if you're calling your functions through function pointers?

Comment: function overriding in C ??  sounds strange

Comment: Do you really need the weak attribute in the function declarations in common.h? Does it make a difference if you remove it from there?

Comment: Sounds like a typical "XY problem", where you are asking how to fix the implementation which is the wrong solution to the actual problem. A few things of note: - Function overloading is a blatantly dangerous feature and therefore no sane languages support it, for many very good reasons. Accidentally calling the wrong function being a major one. - Generic programming or polymorphism in C can/should be done with function pointers. - "Mock" function replacement for test purposes can/should be done with `#define`.

Comment: The compilation line is crucial here. The order of libraries matter, and the switches matter and the `-Wl,-whole-archive` matters. You need to show how did you compile your code.

Comment: @KillianG.it is just simple test code.
I complied like this.

`gcc common.c driverA.c -I.`

Comment: @KamilCuk thank you for your information

Comment: @Lundin "Function overloading is a blatantly dangerous feature and therefore no sane languages support it, for many very good reasons." That is some strong wording for a feature which is in enough languages to make this more of a personal comment than a statement of fact. The situation is not as black and white as stated here

Answer (score 4):

This is happening because the `__attribute__((weak))` declaration in the `common.h` header file applies to BOTH definitions; the one in `common.c` (which you intend to be weak) and also the definition in `driverA.c` (which you intend to be strong).

To get the behavior you want, apply the `__attribute__((weak))` ***only*** in `common.c`, and not in the header file.

Comment: even I tried to move "main" function to common.c and worked well, but I couldn't catch it up.
this test code works well. thank you :)